# The role of voltage-gated ion channels in chemical synapses

Tags: neuroscience, action-potential, synapses

I am trying to understand the mechanisms underlying action potential generation on
the cellular level.

Typically, there is an emphasis on **voltage**-dependent permeability changes of Potassium (K+) and Sodium (Na+) channels which lead to the respective changes of the membrane potential.

Also typically, synapses in the brain are chemical synapses (in contrast to the smaller fraction of electrical synapses, e.g. in the hippocampus, which make use of gap junctions for signal transmission).

My confusion is now this: Chemical synapses depend on neurotransmitters to trigger permeability changes. The canonical explanation of action potentials is with reference to **voltage-gated** channels -- how do these two things go together?

Comment: Have you learned about what neurotransmitters bind to?

Comment: Yes, so I think to understand that they bind to the receptors/ion channels on the neuron's membrane - but then again, it is the NT binding and not the voltage-changes which affect these channels permeability?

Comment: Yes. Those are called ligand-gated channels.

Comment: I understand that, but if an AP is dependent on ligand-gated channels, I still don't see how voltage-gate channels fit into the picture

Comment: When you learn about voltage gated channels and APs, you probably started with resting conditions and then with some depolarization of undescribed origin: it could be by an experimenter or it just "happens". Next you learn about ligand gated channels, which it turns out provide that initial "kick".

Comment: I see, thanks! So what you are saying is that the change in membrane potential which "kicks off" the VGICs is in a first step induced by the ionotropic/metabotropic channels?